# Problem in python3 msg.attach(MIMEImage(file(attachment).read()))

Tags: python, pi, mime-mail

I have a program written in python 2.7, which sends a photo attached to an email. So far I have not had any problems but because I use it and other things in my program I have to upgrade it to python 3 and I encounter the following problems:

```
def sendEmail(self, q, Subject, textBody, attachment, receiver):
  """This method sends an email"""
  EMAIL_SUBJECT = Subject
  EMAIL_USERNAME = 'sistimaasfalias@gmail.com' #Email address.
  EMAIL_FROM = 'Home Security System'
  EMAIL_RECEIVER = receiver
  GMAIL_SMTP = "smtp.gmail.com"
  GMAIL_SMTP_PORT = 587
  GMAIL_PASS = 'HomeSecurity93' #Email password.
  TEXT_SUBTYPE = "plain"

  #Create the email:
  msg = MIMEMultipart()
  msg["Subject"] = EMAIL_SUBJECT
  msg["From"] = EMAIL_FROM
  msg["To"] = EMAIL_RECEIVER
  body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
  body.attach(MIMEText(textBody, TEXT_SUBTYPE ))
  #Attach the message:
  msg.attach(body)
  msgImage = MIMEImage(file.read())
  #Attach a picture:
  if attachment != "NO":
    msg.attach(MIMEImage(file(attachment).read()))
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Process Process-2:2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/homesecurity/functions.py", line 233, in sendEmail
    msgImage = MIMEImage(file.read())
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct.  You haven't defined `file`.  In Python 2, `file` was a built-in type, but that no longer exists.  The `msgImage=MIMEImage(file.read())` would never have made sense, but you aren't using that variable anyway.  Delete that line.

Change

```
  msg.attach(MIMEImage(file(attachment).read()))
```

to

```
  msg.attach(MIMEImage(open(attachment,'rb').read()))
```